# d3: can't import text file with semicolon delimiter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm beginner at JavaScript and at D3 library. There are description for "d3-fetch" module (https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) and for d3.dsv command API (https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv). I can't figure out from these two topics how to make the import with non standard delimiter - semicolon i.e.: dsv parser receives a string as an input. So how to feed it with the whole file?

I typed the non working code, would be grateful for any advises:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var scsv = d3.dsvFormat(";");

        d3.text("$lab/raw.csv").then(function(raw) {
            scsv.parse(raw).then(function(d) {
                    console.log(d);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#dsv):

```js
// set `doc` to your actual url
var doc = 'data:text/plain;base64,' + btoa('cat;dog\n1;0');

d3.dsv(";", doc).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-fetch.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dear @Kosh-Very could you just clarify this trick with base64 encode-decode - what's it for?

Comment: @Andrey, since I don't have your actual `$lab/raw.csv` uri, I used data-uri to fetch. You don't need this trick, just use your `$lab/raw.csv` instead.

Comment: I see. Little extension question about charset for the text file to import: as an old d3 version has been changed (https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md#arbitrary-delimiters), and the old way for charset setting (like `d3.dsv(fieldSeparator, "text/plain; charset=ANSI");`) doesn't work, how it could be set in a new d3 version?

Comment: I mean in a new `d3.dsv(delimiter, input[, init][, row])` construction.

Comment: I managed to code the string without errors: `var init = {data: "text/plain", charset: "ANSI"};`, then I used empty space for the forth parameter in `d3.dsv(";", doc, init, )`. But why in the console Russian letters still shows as question marks in rhombus? The source text file is encoded in ANSI as I could see in FAR.

Comment: winter's coming I'd say). But the ANSI is the charset that I see immediately after "Save as txt" dialogue in MS Excel.