# Read CSV File with React from a static Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, d3.js

I wish to read a CSV file with React from a static Link(Button), no Module, no Drag.

```
import { csv } from "d3";

  const file = "/dummydata/template.csv";

  const readCsv = () => {
    csv(file).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
```

This is my CSV File:

```
Bereitstellung;Beginn;Mitarbeiter;Ende;Wagen ;Sollzeit
;;;;109;21:45
;;;;107;21:45
;;;;104;21:45
;;;;102;21:45
;;;;100;21:45
;;;;97;21:45
;;;;95;22:00
;;;;92;22:00
;;;;90;22:00
;;;;88;22:00
;;;;85;22:15
```

Result which I don't expect:

```
(42) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, columns: Array(1)]
```

Comment: Include `csv` function's definition

Comment: That's not a CSV file. Aside from that, what sort of result are you expecting?

Comment: Please HALP, i actually need this for Wark!!! I have to import CSV automatically on Site loading to feed it current data from Database... in form of CSV and convert it so JSON

Comment: The code you presented appears to work as anticipated, replace your sem-colons with commas or parse the file using d3.dsv ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584286/7106086)), as is your file isn’t a csv file.

Comment: Thank you! But, Database Exports and Saving Excel as CSV uses semicolons instead of commas. I will google d3.dsv for now.

Answer (score 0):

SUCCSESS!

```
import { dsvFormat } from "d3-dsv";
import { text } from "d3-fetch";

var Database;


  const readCsv = () => {
    text("template.csv").then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const psv = dsvFormat(";");
      console.log(psv.parse(data));
      Database = psv.parse(data);
      console.log(Database);
    });
  };
```